# Does there exist a way, within Lambda Calculus, to discover if two free variables are the same?

Tags: lambda-calculus

Using Church's $\lambda x.(\lambda y.y))$ as false and $\lambda x.(\lambda y.x))$ as true, and given two **free** variables $g$ and $h$:

Could there exist a function $eq?$ such that $(eq?\ g\ h)$ is false, and $(eq?\ g\ g)$ is true?

I typically would show my work here, but as of right now, I honestly have nothing except a hunch that it's categorically impossible.

Comment: What do you mean by the truth value of an expression like $(eq?\ g\ h)$ when $g,h$ are free?  I don't believe that's well-defined.  The natural definition would be to say that it reduces to true; but that doesn't make sense for an expression with free variables.

Comment: @D.W. I want to determine whether two free variables are literally the same variable or not.  In Scheme, I can write `(eq? 'A 'A)` and it returns `#t`, whereas `(eq? 'A 'B)` returns `#f`.  (`'A` and `'B` are atoms, not strings, meaning that they behave like $\lambda$-calculus free variables.)  I'm open to any edits or suggestions that would make that clearer.